# how to find context free grammar when ac elements have another element b in between

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am trying to find the context free grammar for this equation

```
L = {a ᶦ b ʲ c ᵏ |  i = j or i = k, i, j, k ≥ 0}
```

I have been able to work out the grammar for when a and b have equal exponent
such as

```
S->ɛ
S->XY
S->ab
S->aXb
Y->cY | ɛ
```

but I am having troubles when I try to do when a and c have the same exponent, as the b now is on the way. Can someone give me some good hints or corrections?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

`S → ab   S → aXb` means, exactly, that `S` is an `ab` surrounded by equal length strings of `a`s and `b`s.

The `ab` is completely orthogonal:

- `S → x   S → a S b`

  x, axb, aaxbb, aaaxbbb, aaaaxbbbb, …
- `S → centre   S → a S b`

  x, acentreb, aacentrebb, aaacentrebbb, aaaacentrebbbb, …
- `S → ε   S → a S b`

  ε, ab, aabb, aaabbb, aaaabbbb, …

It works just the same if the thing in the middle is a non-terminal. Or a sequence of terminals and non-terminals. This is one of the ways you can compose grammars.